# How do I dismiss a TFS Policy Warning

Tags: tfs

TFS has a Policy Warning ("provide a check-in comment") on the Pending Changes panel. It won't go away.  I click the Override Warnings link and it gives me a textbox to type in something, with a Cancel button.  And only a Cancel button.  Perhaps I'm missing something bleedingly obvious, but when I type into the textbox shouldn't there be an OK button appear to accept my input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You enter the override message, then try your check-in again. It reruns the policy at that point in time.

Answer (score 3):

Now the question is do you want a policy check? Did someone else add a policy check and you should comply? or do you just want to remove it.  They first two you'll have to find out on you own but the third one, you need to go to the Team Project Settings (option in Team Explorer) and click on the source control settings and finally navigate to the Check-in policy to remove

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I lack admin rights to do so.  Truthfully the accepted answer only made it go away for a day before it reappeared.  And I'm fine if the policy prevents me from checking in without comment, but then I would expected it to go away on its own after I corrected the issue.  I actually fine with the check itself.